# How to Fix 'Unexpected identifier' error while using an imported function from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

> I am trying to use a function which I defined in another file and
>   exported it. But when I use it and run the node server it throws the
>   error as shown below.

Is it any syntax error I am doing here ?

The Path to the folder is correct and VSCode auto complete also gave
 the same folder path for the file.

```
 'use strict';

  const express = require('express'),
  dotenv = require('dotenv'),  
  path = require('path');

  dotenv.config({ path: path.join('config', 'dev.env') });
  const db_connection = require('./db/db-connection');
  db_connection.dbConnection(); 
  const services = require("./services/notes");
  const app = express(),
  port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
  app.set('view engine', 'pug');
  app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  app.get('/', (req, res) => { 
       res.render('index', {
                 notes: await services.getNotes()
                  });
            });
  app.listen(port, () => {  
         console.log(`Server is up and running on port ${port}`); 
        });
```

File Where I defined the function is:

```
 'use strict';
  const Notes = require('../models/notes');
  async function retrieveNotes() {   
          const notes = await Notes.find().toArray();  
      return notes; 
  } 
  module.exports = { getNotes: retrieveNotes };
```

```
res.render('index', {notes: await services.getNotes()});
                                ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
app.get('/', async (req, res) => { 
  let notes = await services.getNotes();
  res.render('index', {notes}); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The "unexpected identifier" is the keyword `await`, which is only allowed inside *asynchronous* functions.

Like edwin walela says, you can make your `app.get` callback function asynchronous by changing:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => { ...
```

to:

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => { ...
```